# Distribution of density operators under Stochastic Master Equation

Tags: density-matrix, open-quantum-systems, master-equation

Stochastic master equations (SME) are used in studies of open quantum systems. The general form of an SME is:
\begin{align}
\tag{1} d\tilde{\sigma}(t) = - i [H, \tilde{\sigma}(t) ]dt + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^d \left([L_j \tilde{\sigma}(t), L_j^*] + [L_j, \tilde{\sigma}(t) L_j^*] \right) dt 
\\ +\sum_{j=1}^d \left( L_j \tilde{\sigma}(t) + \tilde{\sigma}(t) L_j^* \right)dW_j,
\end{align}
where $\tilde{\sigma}(t)$ could be viewed as non-normalized density operator, $L_j$ is a Lindblad operator and $dW_j$ is a stochastic differential.

If we drop the stochastic term in Eq (1) then we get the usual master equation in the Lindblad form.

It is possible to obtain the density operator $\tilde{\rho}(t)$ from $\tilde{\sigma}(t)$ as follows:
$$
\tilde{\rho}(t) = \tilde{\sigma}(t)/Tr(\tilde{\sigma}(t)).
$$

Since Eq (1) is a stochastic differential equation, $\tilde{\rho}(t)$ is a solution which is also random.

**Could anyone tell me what's the distribution of $\tilde{\rho}(t)$ is?**
**Any beginner-level relevant resources are also very much appreciated!**

In short, I would like to know the following:
$$
\tilde{\rho}(t) \sim \ ?
$$

What I have figured out so far:
If we take the expectation of Eq (1) we get the Lindblad master equation, and its solution $\rho(t)$ is the mean of $\tilde{\rho}(t)$, i.e.
$$
\mathbb{E}\left( \tilde{\rho}(t) \right) = \rho(t).
$$

Comment: For a pedagogical, beginner-level, derivation of the Lindblad master equation without the stochastic term see [this](http://https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.04478). I never worked with stochastic master equations, but [Pierre Rouchon](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.07416) is a name which I associate them to. I hope this helps.

Comment: @GFrazao thanks for the links, although the first link doesn't work. I've seen the paper by Pierre Rouchon and unfortunately, it doesn't have the info I need.

Comment: It seems that there are algorithms solving it numerically(I think searching stochastic master equation will find the ref easily? Not sure if [this link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.00967) helps), but I'm not sure if there is a method to solve this analytically for the general case.

Comment: this looks very interesting thanks @narip

Comment: MonteNero: the first link missed a ":" after "https". @narip: cool ref, it will help me too.